# Multiple Plots in R Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm attempting to display multiple plots in my main panel in my Shiny app.

I am using the multiplot function from [R cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/)

```
multiplot <- function(..., plotlist=NULL, file, cols=1, layout=NULL) {
library(grid)

# Make a list from the ... arguments and plotlist
plots <- c(list(...), plotlist)

numPlots = length(plots)

# If layout is NULL, then use 'cols' to determine layout
if (is.null(layout)) {
  # Make the panel
  # ncol: Number of columns of plots
  # nrow: Number of rows needed, calculated from # of cols
  layout <- matrix(seq(1, cols * ceiling(numPlots/cols)),
                   ncol = cols, nrow = ceiling(numPlots/cols))
}

if (numPlots==1) {
  print(plots[[1]])

} else {
  # Set up the page
  grid.newpage()
  pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(nrow(layout), ncol(layout))))

  # Make each plot, in the correct location
  for (i in 1:numPlots) {
    # Get the i,j matrix positions of the regions that contain this subplot
    matchidx <- as.data.frame(which(layout == i, arr.ind = TRUE))

    print(plots[[i]], vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = matchidx$row,
                                    layout.pos.col = matchidx$col))
  }
}
}
```

And then calling multiplot

```
    multiplot(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6, cols=1)
```

But it looks like it's trying to squish everything in to the main panel

[image]

Here is what my app looks like with only one plot

[image]

Here is my ui.R

```
    shinyUI(fluidPage(


  titlePanel("Baseball"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        "var", label = "Choose a group to visualize",
        choices =c(Overall = "overall", Offense = "offense", Pitchers = "pitchers", Simpsons = "simpsons"),
        selected = "offense")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plotOffense")

    )
    )
    )
    )
```

Do I need to be using something instead of mainPanel that allows for more graphics to be placed in the browser?

Comment: You have an HTML container that you are putting your plot in.  `multiplot` has nothing to do with its sizing. You may be satisfied with simply increasing the height of this container, `plotOutput("plotOffense", height="800px")`.  You could make this more 'programmatic' but it would probably require delving quite a bit deeper.

Comment: but a much simpler solution would be to not use the `multiplot` function and just make a separate `renderPlot` and `plotOutput` for each one of your plots.

Comment: @bunk thanks, I'll look into changing the height.  your second comment is my back up plan. but the plots are going to depend on what the user selects in the drop down list. I'll have to figure out a way to capture the user input in UI.R

Comment: @bunk producing 10 plots based on the user input. if a user selects offense, then 10 plots will appear, if a user selects 'pitching' then 10 different plots will appear for different players.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, there are really just two things that have to happen: `plotOutput` should be called to create the div for the actual output, and `renderPlot` needs to be called to format the plot in the correct way.  So, here are a some functions that can do this dynamically, and let you play with the width/height/number of columns, similar to the multiplot, only in a shiny way.  Refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/wch/5436415) as well.

I separated things into functions, but it could be just put straight into the server function as well.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, the width and height entry boxes are text, and should be valid CSS, so it could be 10, 10px, or 10% for example.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

## Some sample data
dat <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(runif(100),10)), letters[1:10])
dat$time <- seq(nrow(dat))

## Make some random plots because it looks cooler
## But you would just define your 10 different plots
rndmPlot <- function(input)
    sample(list(geom_line(), geom_bar(stat='identity'), geom_point(), geom_jitter(),
               geom_density(aes_string(x=input$var), inherit.aes=FALSE)), 1)

makePlotContainers <- function(n, ncol=2, prefix="plot", height=100, width="100%", ...) {
    ## Validate inputs
    validateCssUnit(width)
    validateCssUnit(height)

    ## Construct plotOutputs
    lst <- lapply(seq.int(n), function(i)
        plotOutput(sprintf('%s_%g', prefix, i), height=height, width=width))

    ## Make columns
    lst <- lapply(split(lst, (seq.int(n)-1)%/%ncol), function(x) column(12/ncol, x))
    do.call(tagList, lst)
}

renderPlots <- function(n, input, output, prefix="plot") {
    for (i in seq.int(n)) {
        local({
            ii <- i  # need i evaluated here
            ## These would be your 10 plots instead
            output[[sprintf('%s_%g', prefix, ii)]] <- renderPlot({
                ggplot(dat, aes_string(x='time', y=input$var)) + rndmPlot(input)
            })
        })
    }
}

ui <- shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                sliderInput('nplots', 'Number of Plots', min=1, max=10, value=8),
                selectInput("var", label = "Choose", choices=letters[1:10]),
                textInput('height', 'Plot Height', value="100"),
                textInput('width', 'Width', value="100%"),
                sliderInput('ncol', 'Columns', min=1, max=3, value=2)
            ),
            mainPanel(
                uiOutput('plots')
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$plots <- renderUI({
        makePlotContainers(input$nplots, ncol=input$ncol, height=input$height, width=input$width)
    })
    observeEvent(input$nplots, renderPlots(input$nplots, input, output))
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thanks! I'll give it a shot when I get home from work tonight.