# R Shiny: rendering multiple plots - why local() is required?

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to shiny, and building an app based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469773/multiple-plots-in-r-shiny?rq=1)

But there is a section in the code I do not understand, and can not find more insight in shiny documents.
In the code section below (part of [the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469773)), why the use of local? and the ii <- i assignment?

My apologies if this is not a proper stackoverflow question! this is my first one..

```
renderPlots <- function(n, input, output, prefix="plot") {
    for (i in seq.int(n)) {
        local({
            ii <- i  # need i evaluated here
            ## These would be your 10 plots instead
            output[[sprintf('%s_%g', prefix, ii)]] <- renderPlot({
                ggplot(dat, aes_string(x='time', y=input$var)) + rndmPlot(input)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is in [the gist](https://gist.github.com/wch/5436415) in the question that you linked.  You need `local` to force  evaluate the `i` to each element of the loop, else the `i` value will be the same across each plot.